Help with Mysterious iCloud Email on My Account and Apple ID Management
I recently bought an iPhone and tried logging in with my existing Apple account, which I created a long time ago. When I checked the "Sign-In and Security" section, I noticed that my account had a primary email ID and also an unfamiliar iCloud email address (xxxxx@icloud.com). I have no idea how that iCloud email got linked to my account, as I never created it.
I contacted Apple Support about this, and they mentioned that Apple cannot delete the iCloud email. This has made me feel like my account might be compromised.
Additionally, I asked Apple Support if they could remove my primary Apple ID (which is a Gmail address) so that I can create a new Apple account with the same Gmail address.
I'm concerned about the security of my account and don't want any unknown Apple ID associated with it.
Can someone kindly help me resolve this issue?

Not sure which issue you want to resolve, you mention several. Also, Apple Support usually is the best place to go to for AppleID/Apple Account issues, what did they recommend?

I need  to remove Icould  email id from my account , else, I need new apple account with orimary email ID

They mentioned that we could not able to delete the iCloud email ID

If Apple Support tells you that it's not possible, I'm not sure what kind of additional help people here can provide. Also, AFAIR, Apple Account addresses can't be reused to prevent misuse.

There’s not much you can resolve. Apple highly restricts the ability to reuse an external ID already associated in any way with an existing iCloud account if anyone (including you) makes a new iCloud account.

You’re not sharing where exactly this long ago created account has iCloud.com email address associated. It could be parental, security backup, trusted recovery, primary Apple ID or simply what the system suggested for your iCloud when your brought (for instance) a Gmail or yahoo or Hotmail email for your Apple ID. Same confusion exists on how your other emails are used. Only Apple support can clearly see your account unless you document a ton of screen shots or share a screen with someone for about 15 methodical minutes to explore all nooks and corners of iCloud service setup.
Every iCloud account has the option have an iCloud mail address and it’s very common (or was in the past) for people to click through and opt in to an iCloud or .me or .mac email and then ignore that if an external email is their log in string to the account (instead of a phone number or iCloud email).
I would focus on how secure the account is now and avoid making a new account unless you understand in writing from Apple support clearly that you will be able to detach an external mail from the old account and exactly how you will use or attach it to a new iCloud account.

It’s far easier to just secure the account you have. No one can use or abuse that xxx@icloud.com if you have two factor security and a strong, unique password.
In summery, don’t try to resolve this. Secure your account if it mostly works. Work with Apple support on this, they are far better than we can ever be with securing your specific iCloud.

What do you mean by "Every iCloud account has to have an iCloud mail"? When I look at my iCloud settings, it says "Setup" under "Mail" -- it's still waiting for me to create iCloud mail.

I was wondering if Apple relaxed that push to be an opt in reviewing the KB just now. In the past, it seemed to be a lot harder to avoid getting Apple email with each account - let me change the wording for that sentence. Thanks @Barmar !

Yeah, I probably opted out when I first created my iCloud account.
